# Node.js scraping with the request module

Tags: html, node.js, web, web-scraping

I want to get html from a web. But it show like that.

> meta http-equiv=refresh content="0;url=http://www.skku.edu/errSkkuPage.jsp">

But when I use https://www.naver.com/ instead of https://www.skku.edu/skku/index.do, it works well.

I want to know the reason.

Here's my code.

```
var request = require('request');

const url = "https://www.skku.edu/skku/index.do";

request(url, function(error, response, body){
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website blocks the request that is coming from programmatic script checking User-Agent in the request header.
Pass the user-Agent that web-browser(eg: Google chrome) sends and it should work.

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://www.skku.edu/skku/index.do',
    'headers': {
    'User-Agent': ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'
 }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can get a html in that web-page too.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend `request` module as it is not maintained for changes anymore. see it here - https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

You could look for alternatives in form of `got`, `axios` etc which makes code much more readable and clear. And most important thing - Native support for promises and async/await The above code will look like

```
var got = require('got');

const url = "https://www.skku.edu/skku/index.do";

(async () => {
  const response = await got(url);
  console.log(response.body);
})();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question